# How do I use ReactElement type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, tsx

i am looking into using Typescript with React and I came across type "ReactElement", it's definition is:

```
interface ReactElement<P = any, T extends string | JSXElementConstructor<any> = string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> {
  type: T;
  props: P;
  key: Key | null;
}
```

Because we can specify the type of props we want our ReactElement to return I figured the following code should result in an error:

```
type HeadingProps = {
    text : string,
}

const Heading = (props: HeadingProps): ReactElement<{}, any> => {
    return <h1>{props.text}</h1>
}

export default Heading
```

I passed into generic empty object so I expected an error, but it still works fine, am I doing something wrong or did I not get the point of "ReactElement"?

Comment: You don't need that type annotation at all, the compiler can infer it just fine by the fact you're returning JSX and that you've typed your props.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create an interface to specify which data a variable can receive for example:

```
    interface ButtonProps {
     color?: 'green' | 'blue' | 'sky'
     text: string
}

export default function Button(props: ButtonProps)
```

in this example above I specify that the props of my button component will be of these types, for example color as there is a ? before: it is a property that may or may not be passed on, it is optional, the text property is required to be passed on, I did not put the ? and in it you will have to pass a string argument.

I hope it helps you :)